# Hibernate Self reference related Entities

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I have created a Hibernate mapping where an Entity can have many relations to Entities of the same type.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class HelpEntity {

    public static final String MASTER_HELP = "masterHelp";
    public static final String MASTER_HELP_ID = "masterHelpId";

    private HelpEntity masterHelp;
    private List<HelpEntity> referencedHelps = new ArrayList<HelpEntity>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = HelpEntity.MASTER_HELP)
    public List<HelpEntity> getReferencedHelps() {
        return referencedHelps;
    }

    public void setReferencedHelps(List<HelpEntity> referencedHelps) {
        this.referencedHelps = referencedHelps;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = HelpEntity.MASTER_HELP_ID)
    public HelpEntity getMasterHelp() {
        return masterHelp;
    }

    public void setMasterHelp(HelpEntity masterHelp) {
        this.masterHelp = masterHelp;
    }

}
```

This is working like expected and I can create HelpEntities that have some other "related" Objects.

Now the problem comes during delete ...
I nearly tried everything to delete the objects from references, but every time I get

org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [xxx.HelpEntity#2]

HelpEntity#2 is the first referencedHelp ...

```
private static boolean deleteHelp(HelpEntity entity) {

    Session session = manager.getCurrentSession();

    try {

        session.beginTransaction();

        List<HelpEntity> forDeletion = new ArrayList<HelpEntity>();
        for (HelpEntity reference : entity.getReferencedHelps()) {
            reference.setMasterHelp(null);
            forDeletion.add(reference);
        }

        entity.setReferencedHelps(null);

        for (HelpEntity reference : forDeletion) {
            session.delete(reference);
        }

        session.delete(entity);

        manager.commit(session);

        return true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

}
```